# Understanding Detection API config file

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, coco

I want to use "coco_detection_metrics". I read in forums that I should add **metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"** to eval_config:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples:2000
  max_evals: 10
  eval_interval_secs: 5
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
}
```

But there are two config files for each model and I see "eval_config" in both of them, for example for "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco":

1- **ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config**

```
(located in: **samples/configs/**)
```

2- ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/**pipeline.config**

```
(located in: **ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz**)
```

Which one should be modified? What is the difference of these two files? Which one will be used during training or evaluation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the one that you pass to the train.py script as a flag:

```
python3 object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=/path/to/your/config_file.config --train_dir=/your/train/dir
```

So, create your config file wherever on your file system, modify it as you want, and then pass it to the train or eval scripts as shown above.